# How can I get two list levels on the same line in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting

So my problem is similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/326439/how-to-have-two-headings-at-the-same-level-in-a-multilevel-list) except for the fact that I don't need a header, but only the subheaders, is there a way to set a list with just sub headers?

Example:

```
1.1. Heading 1 of item 1
1.2. Heading 2 of item 1
2.1. Heading 1 of item 2
2.2. Heading 2 of item 2
3.1. etc
3.2. etc
```

Can you do this in word? I have search extensively on how to do it, but I find no answer whatsoever.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with just one list - there's no way for Word to know when you were switching items to restart headings?  You could create multiple lists, with no space between them . . .

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want - Type `1.` and press space once - type your first point, main heading, or whatever you'd like.

Press `Enter`. It should say `2.`. Backspace once, type `1.1.`, space, then your text. Press enter and it should go to `1.2.`. When you want to go to `2` instead of `1.x.`, just backspace the `1.x.`, type `2.`, and then space - and repeat the process for `2.x.`.

Hope this helps.

Note: If you want to start with `1.1.` (which I think was your question), just type `1.1.` and then space - then the next line will be `1.2.`, it's basically the same process just leaving off the `1.`.