# Having custom numbering format inbetween normal numbered list / two list levels on the same line as a different format

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

What I basically want is an MS Word list formatted in a way like this:

```
1. First step
   * do this and that
   * here is an example
2a. Next step for use case A
   * do stuff
2b. Alternative next step for use case B
   * do different stuff
3. Last step
   * do more
```

I've not been able to figure out how to accomplish this. There is a similar question ([How can I get two list levels on the same line in Microsoft Word](https://superuser.com/q/518660/1886967)) which talks about this with a format like "2.1" instead of "2a.". This works fine in Word, but as soon as I enter "2a."/"2a"/"2.a" and press space, it doesn't autoformat it into a list.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Look into using the Style Separator. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Style_Separator

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Thank you! I will have a look at it.